# Is there any difference in terms of performance between those 2 cycles

Tags: performance, loops

I wanted to know if there's any difference in terms of performance between these two cycles.

I already know they give the same result, but I always see both I'd like to know why does one get picked instead of another.

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
   //
}


for (let i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
   //
}
```

Comment: This is dependent of the target language and runtime/compilers tools but generally the answer is no. Please indicate the language used.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I am using Javascript.

Comment: Javascript codes are both interpreted and compiled. Once compiled this code can be completely optimized out to nothing. Even if it would not be, <= and < are translated to instructions of the same cost on all modern x86-64 processor (and high-end ARM ones). When interpreted, all iteration will be executed but the overhead of the comparison should be quite small compared to interpreting the code. Put it shortly, it has no impact in this case.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no difference between `i < 101` and `i <= 100`. Even if there was, it wouldn't be a difference you could detect.

Rather than worrying about any microoptimizations like this, concern yourself with which makes more sense to the human reader. If you're counting up to 100, then `i <= 100` will make more sense to human readers.